# Responsive icons and texts inside of a footer and also make the whole footer responsive as well

Tags: html, css

I'm still a newbie myself in HTML and CSS, in my screen...I tried those elements that I circled in this photo: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DS9G.jpg) ...... always came out the footer and other text

hides behind the input[This2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2oUB.jpg).. And for the footer, it was ok on my laptop screen but when I try to open my web on a bigger pc screen and resize the browser even though I am using meta<> or @media,  it still didn't work... [This3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzYxU.jpg)

What should I do??

This is what I wanted to look like (no matter what screen or browser size is...) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP6C5.jpg)

Here's are codes:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: serif;
}

a{text-decoration: none;}


.footer{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24rem;
    color: white;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0px;
    margin: auto;
    
}
.footer .box{
    width:auto;
    display:table;
    padding-left: 8%; 
    padding-bottom: auto;
    

}
.footer .box .box-row{
    display:table-row;
    
}
.footer .box .box-cell{
    display:table-cell;
    padding:0.6em;
    


}
.box-cell.shop{
    color: white;

}
.box-cell.service{
    color: white;
}
.box-cell.about{
    color: white;
    
}
.footer-title{
    font-size:1.5vw;
    padding-bottom:0.5em;
    
}
.list1{
    font-size:1vw;
    font-weight: 10;
    padding-bottom:0.6em;
    
}
.box2{top: -62%;
    position:relative;


}

.connect{
    left: 80%;
    bottom:-2.1em;
    font-size:1.5vw;
    position:relative;
}

.signupmessage{
    font-weight: 80;
    color:white;
    left:-1%;
    font-size:1vw;
    bottom:-7em;
    position:relative;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 110px;

}
.input1{
    position:relative;
    left: -1%;
    bottom:-2.5em;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right:20px;
}

#text1
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 2.5em;
    width: 24%;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: #999;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    position: relative;
    left:13px;
    


}

#subbutton
{
    border: solid 1px black;
    background-color:white;
    height: 3.3em;
    width:6%;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:5px;
    font-size: 0.8vw;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;  
    left: 0.2%;
    bottom:-0.3em;
    

}
#subbutton:hover{
    background-color:coral;
    font-weight: 600;
    
}

.socialmedia{
position:relative;
padding-right:80px;
left:-1%;
bottom: -2.9em;
text-align: right;
}

.fa {
    padding:0.5%;
    width: 4%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-left: 1%;
    position:relative;
    width: min(3vw, 200px);
  }
  
  .fa:hover {
      opacity: 0.7;
  }
  
  .fa-facebook {
    background:white;
    color: black;
  }
  
  .fa-instagram {
    color: white;
  }
  
  
  .fa-pinterest {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .fa-twitter {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }

  .fa-youtube-play {
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }

  .payment{
      bottom: -6.5em;
      font-size:0.9em; 
      color:white;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<footer class ="footer">
    <div class = "box">
        <div class ="box-row">
            <div class = "box-cell shop">
                <ul class = "ullist" style = "list-style-type:none;"><p class = "footer-title">SHOP</p>
                <li class = "list1">Features</li>
                <li class = "list1">Most popular</li>
                <li class = "list1">Flowers</li>
                <li class = "list1">Plants</li>
                <li class = "list1">Gifts</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class = "box-cell service">
                <ul class = "ullist" style = "list-style-type:none;"><p class = "footer-title">SERVICE</p>
                <li class = "list1">About Us</li>
                <li class = "list1">Contact</li>
                <li class = "list1">Delivery</li>
                <li class = "list1">FAQs</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
             <div class = "box-cell about">
                <ul class = "ullist" style = "list-style-type:none;"><p class = "footer-title">ABOUT</p>
                <li class = "list1">Location</li>
                <li class = "list1">Blog</li>
                <li class = "list1">Fresh Flowers Guaranteed</li>
                <li class = "list1">Terms and Conditions</li>
                <li class = "list1">Site Map</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class ="box2">
            <label class ="connect" style = "text-align: center; color:white;">CONNECT</label>
        <div class = "signupmessage">
        <p>SIGN UP FOR OUR NEWS LETTER</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "input1">
        <input type = "text" id = "text1" value = "Your Email Address"/>
        <input type = "button" id = "subbutton" value ="&#9668; Subscribe">
        </div>
        

        <div class = "socialmedia">
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
            <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
        </div>

        <div class ="payment">
            <i class="fa fa-cc-visa"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-cc-mastercard"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-cc-paypal"></i>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently you have used 'Box' and 'Box2' class in footer. I think it would be better if you could separate the payment icon div form the 'Box2' and directly placing it as the child of the class 'footer'. it would make it easy for you.

also the css looks kind of messed up. Is it ok to use the flex property!?

Comment: yeah, i think its ok to use flex property... i will try to fix right now. thanks for the little  tip.